# Stop AsyncTAsk on listview scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

on the method `getview()` of my `Adapter` in `Listview`, I have a `AsyncTask` to load image from URL.

It's work well, but I don't understand if the adapter on `scrolling` cancel the asynctask on running.

Can someone help me?

Comment: please share your code, for better understanding

Comment: Perhaps the view (which has an asynctask attached) is destroyed when it's not on screen anymore.

Comment: I don't think this is best practice for what you're trying to do. Can you clarify a little more about the image loading? Someone may be able to recommend a good library or tool to do this.

Comment: Do you want to cancel the running AsyncTask ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Picasso image loader library... You won't need an async task..

Comment: I tryed to use Picasso but it seems like it doen't work with ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to use Picasso but it seems like it doen't work with ImageButton. Besides, I have also to save in SDCard after get Image by URL. I don't have problem with the Load Image Async Task, It works fine, but I don't understand if automatically ListAdapter destroy AsyncTask no longer viewed in ListView after scrolling if the AsyncTask is still in running.